# Installed application not shown in dash

Tags: launcher, unity-dash

I have just installed WebStorm to my 16.04. Once I close the app, it's no longer opening from the launcher. I can go to directory and type `./webstorm.sh`everytime but isn't it kind of weird? How can I open WebStorm by clicking the icon?

Comment: When `WebStorm` is open an icon for it appears on the left-side panel?

Comment: yes it has its own icon

Comment: Then 'right-click' on it and select **Lock to launcher**

Comment: Did you log out/in afterwards?

Comment: no option for it

Comment: @Danabey ? You cannot logout? Why not?

Comment: @JacobVlijm no I mean, no option for lock to launcher, I can logout.

Comment: @Danabey did you log out and back in?

Comment: yes it doesn't change anything. I can still open the WebStorm from terminal by typing ./webstorm.sh and it automatically opens my latest project, even if I deleted the folders and reinstaled it. But still ubuntu can't detect Webstorm as an installed program. How can I completely remove it with every file and folder it has , and then clearly reinstall it?